# How to extend an existing list with values of a dictionary as a string?

Tags: string, list, dictionary, key-value, listof

How to extend an existing list with values of a dictionary as a string in below Python codes?

`x = [ 'h1', 'h2' ]`

`y = [ 'h3', 'h4' ]`

`dict_sample = {'xyz': ['ab', 'bc'], 'mno': ['cd', 'de']}`

`x.extend(dict_sample.keys()) ---> (Output) ['h1', 'h2', 'xyz', 'mno']`

`y.extend(dict_sample.values()) ----> (Output) ['h3', 'h4', ['ab', 'bc'], ['cd', 'de']]`

However, how to obtain the below desired output for second case?

`['h3', 'h4', '['ab', 'bc']', '['cd', 'de']']`

Comment: are you referring to this output `['h3', 'h4', '["ab", "bc"]', '["cd", "de"]']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the desired output looks like `['h3', 'h4', '["ab", "bc"]', '["cd", "de"]']`,
which includes stringified json elements, here's a way to do it:

```py
import json

y = [ 'h3', 'h4' ]
dict_sample = {'xyz': ['ab', 'bc'], 'mno': ['cd', 'de']}

y.extend([json.dumps(e) for e in dict_sample.values()])
print(y)
```

Comment: thanks, would you help to upvote my answer as well please?